# WeChat Miniprogram send object from ts to wxs file

Tags: wechat, wechat-miniprogram

I am creating a WeChat miniprogram using typescript, I have a Person type class with the following data:

```
export class Person {
   dob: Date;
   firstName: String;
   lastName: String;
}
```

Create Person object:

```
let person = new Person ();
person.dob = new Date ();
person.fisrtName = "XXX";
person.lastName = "YYY";

this.setData ({
person: person
})
```

At the time of displaying it in the wxml I am doing the following:

```
<view> {{person.firstName}} </view>
<view> {{person.lastName}} </view>
<view> {{person.dob}} </view>
```

The `dob` property shows it as **[object Object]**

I have created a method in a wxs file to transform the `dob` property and display it as a string by calling the `toDateString` method of the Date object, but it gives me the following error:
**dob.toDateString() is not a function**, if I call this method from the **.ts** file it works fine but when I call it from the wxs file it gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript environment and wxs environment of view is divided.I guess you may try to require the wxs file in wxml like this：

Comment: Hello @taolu, the answer is incomplete